# Set HTML5 placeholder attribute conditionally in aspx

Tags: asp.net

I have an `aspx` that has a server control TextBox

```
<asp:TextBox placeholder="myPlaceholder" ID="myID" runat="server" />
```

**I'd like to set the HTML5 attribute placeholder conditionally**.

I tried this but with no success because server controls cannot have `<% %>`

```
<asp:TextBox <% if(this.ShowVatNumberCodePlaceholder) {  %>placeholder="myPlaceholder" runat="server" ID="myID" <%}%> />
```

Inspired by my WPF knowledge i shot in the dark with this

```
<asp:TextBox ID="sttxBillToVatNumber" MaxLength="10" runat="server">
    <% if (this.ShowVatNumberCodePlaceholder)
       {
           %>
    placeholder="myPlaceholder"
    <%
       }
               %>
</asp:TextBox>
```

From my readings i guess i can only do this in the server side - which i did and it works.

But I'd rather have this logic in the aspx to avoid scattering the presentation logic across the two files.

Is there any way i **can achieve this in the `aspx` itself**?

Comment: try the associate placeholder using JQuery.

   <% if (this.ShowVatNumberCodePlaceholder)
       {
    $("#<%sttxBillToVatNumber.ClientID"%>").attr("placeholder","myPlaceholder");
    
       }
    %>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with a combination of the ternary operator and the DataBind call like this.

Markup

```
<asp:TextBox ID="sttxBillToVatNumber" runat="server" 
         MaxLength="10"
        placeholder='<%# this.ShowVatNumberCodePlaceholder ? "my_placeholder" : "my_other_placeholder" %>'>
</asp:TextBox>
```

Code Behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        sttxBillToVatNumber.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try associate placeholder using JQuery. something like:

```
$(function () {
    <% if (this.ShowVatNumberCodePlaceholder)
    {
        $("#<%sttxBillToVatNumber.ClientID"%>").attr("placeholder","myPlaceholder");
    }
    %>
});
```